# $\epsilon-\delta$ proof for $ \lim _ {x \rightarrow 9}\frac{x-9}{\sqrt{x}-3}=6. $

Tags: proof-verification, epsilon-delta

> I want to prove that
>
> $$ \lim _ {x \rightarrow 9}\frac{x-9}{\sqrt{x}-3}=6. $$

Here is my approach:

For all $\epsilon >0 $ Let $\delta = \epsilon$, then whenever we have that $|x-9|<\delta$, we know that :

$$\left|\frac{x-9}{\sqrt x-3}-6\right|=\left|\frac{(\sqrt x-3)(\sqrt x+3)}{\sqrt x-3}-6\right|=\left|\sqrt x+3-6\right|=|\sqrt x-3|. $$
Now notice that
$$|\sqrt x-3|< |\sqrt x-3|\cdot |\sqrt x+3|=|x-9|<\delta=\epsilon. \square$$

Is my proof sufficient - I'm not sure about the final step, is it okay what I do here?

Comment: I would do the simplification $\frac{x - 9}{\sqrt{x}-3} = \sqrt{x} + 3$ that you have recognised in your first displayed equation first of all . I.e., prove that $\lim_{x \to 9}\sqrt{x}+3 = 6$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you can also solve the simplified limit $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 9} \sqrt{x} +3 =6$$