# Using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ , show $\lim \limits_{x\to 9} \frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{x-9} = \frac16$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I know how to show that the limit of the function is equal to $1/6$ through general calculus methods, but being in a real analysis course, I would like to try to use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ method to prove the limit is $1/6$

The goal is to show $\displaystyle \lim \limits_{x\to 9} \frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{x-9} = \frac16$

My attempts:

$$\left| \frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{x-9} - \frac16\right| = \left| \frac{6\sqrt{x}-9-x}{6(x-9)} \right| = \left| \frac{1}{x-9} \right|\left|\frac{6\sqrt{x}-9-x}{6} \right|$$
but this doesn't help me

Next attempt I tried was simplifying the function first:
$$\left| \frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{x-9} - \frac16\right| = \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+3 }-\frac16 \right| = \left|\frac{3-\sqrt{x}}{6(\sqrt{x}+3)} \right| = \left|{x-9}\right| \left|\frac{1}{6(\sqrt{x}+3)^2} \right|$$

But at this point I begin to wonder why we need $\frac{1}{6}$ as it doesn't appear to have much of an important role.

Coincidentally this problem is very similar to [$ϵ$−$δ$ proof for $\lim_{x→9} \frac{x−9}{\sqrt{x}−3}=6$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2978402/epsilon-delta-proof-for-lim-x-rightarrow-9-fracx-9-sqrtx-3-6) but I would like to see a solution that doesn't involve this question then simply taking the reciprocal.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you find an upper bound on the size of $\left|\frac{1}{6(\sqrt{x}+3)^2} \right|$ when $0<|x-9|<1$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes, it believe it is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{6(\sqrt{8}+3)^2}$

Comment: OK, I see that @Arthur has shown you how to use that.

Comment: If you're wondering why you need $1/6$, well, that's what the limit is; it's the only number that will work. After working through the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof, then try it again with any different number, say $1/7$, and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Take your second attempt. Then declare that no matter what, you will never pick $\delta$ larger than $1$. That means that we have decided, before even looking at our $\epsilon$, that $x\in (8,10)$. With this restriction, we get
$$
\left|\frac1{6(\sqrt{x}+3)^2}\right|<0.005
$$
Now, since $|x-9|<\delta$, we get that the entire expression is less than $0.005\delta$, for any valid $x$. So given an $\epsilon>0$, picking something like $\delta=\min(\epsilon, 1)$ is going to work nicely.

Comment: Technically, you don't need to restriction of $x\in(8,10)$, since $\frac{1}{6(\sqrt{x}+3)^2}\leq\frac{1}{6\cdot 3^2}=\frac{1}{54}$ for all $x$ where $\sqrt{x}$ is defined.

Comment: Would I not want $\delta = \min(\epsilon / 0.005, 1)$? As once I plug in, I would have $$\left|{x-9}\right| \left|\frac{1}{6(\sqrt{x}+3)^2} \right| < \left.|{x-9}\right|(0.005)$$

Comment: You can use $\delta = \min(\epsilon/0.005,1).$ But $\epsilon\leq \epsilon/0.005$ so we can also use the smaller $\delta=\min(\epsilon,1).$ @WaveX

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You're right. Just like I could've used $0.005\epsilon$ instead of $\epsilon$, I could've used $\delta\leq9$ rather than $\delta\leq1$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier if you start with your second approach: $$\frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{x-9}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}+3}.$$

Note that when $\sqrt{x}$ is defined, $3+\sqrt{x}\geq{3}$, so $$\frac{1}{6(3+\sqrt{x})^2}<\frac{1}{6\cdot 3^2}=\frac{1}{54}$$

So you have:

$$\left|{x-9}\right| \left|\frac{1}{6(\sqrt{x}+3)^2} \right|\leq\frac{|x-9|}{54}.$$

So given $\epsilon>0$ we can take $\delta = 54\epsilon.$ Then given $x$ is the domain of $\frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{x-9}$ (that is $x\geq 0$) and $|x-9|<\delta$ then $$\left|\frac{\sqrt{x}-3}{x-9}-\frac{1}{6}\right|<\frac{\delta}{54}=\epsilon.$$

(Some people might set $\delta = \min(9,54\epsilon),$ but it isn't really necessary in this case to protect again $x<0$ since that is already excluded from our domain.)

Comment: Yep, typo, fixed. @WaveX